# Как создать новый пост в wordpress, обратившись к своему сайту по ajax

Tags: wordpress

Нужно создать на своем сайте новый или отредактировать существующий пост (запись), обратившись к сайту get-запросом.

*Например так:*

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET', 
      url: 'https://my-site.com/', 
      data: {
        title: 'Это заголовок поста',
        post: 'Тут текст поста',
        // Другие параметры поста, сео заголовок, сео описание, назначить категорию, назначить метки, другое
    },
    contentType: 'application/javascript',
    dataType: 'jsonp'
});
```

Можно ли это как-то реализовать?
Спасибо

Comment: Нафика аякс я не понимаю (как минимум авторизация же), а так https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/

Comment: Да я видел эту документацию, но понятия не имею как ее применить. Я в php не силен, да и английский не знаю.

Comment: Тогда  есть 2 пути - либо учить php и ВП, либо платить специалистам. (анг можно и гугпереводчиком перевести).

Comment: И все равно php нужно, если ajax